# What's the sensible way to name Xcode targets?

Tags: xcode

I've got an Xcode project, let's say it's called `Floppy Bird`, that runs on OS/X, tvOS and iOS. Each of those has a different target, but I feel like I'm naming them in an unexpected way (I'm calling them `OSX`, `tvOS` and `iOS`).

But this causes the built apps to be called those target names unless I make extra effort to change those names - I want them all to be called `Floppy Bird`.

It makes me feel like I'm doing it wrong. Surely I'm not expected to have different projects for each platform? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this causes the built apps to be called those target names unless I make extra effort to change those names - I want them all to be called Floppy Bird.

Target names are arbitrary and not user-facing and you should use whatever is useful to you; your OSX, tvOS and iOS suffixes are eminently sensible and you should keep doing that.

The same is true of project names.

The only user-facing name is the CFBundleDisplayName which it takes only a moment to set in the *Info.plist* file. You should make a habit of setting this always, and let go of all notion of connection between project/target name and this user-facing name.

Comment: When I produce an archive to upload to iTunes Connect it still calls it `iOS` which is a little opaque, so I'll just mention here that `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Archive > Archive Name` is the place to fix that, it seems. Thanks for the useful information kindly delivered.

Comment: The archive name is not user facing either. It is just a container.

Comment: It faces me though, and probably beta testers. Perhaps "Floppy Bird - iOS" or something like that is the best name for a target.